# Getting values from response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I am getting the response from an external api like the given below screenshot.

How can i get the value of id i.e., `3991938`

[image]

Here is how i do the request.

```
 $http.post('http://api.quickblox.com/users.json', {

token: quickbloxapitoken,
user: {

    email: email,
    login: email,
    password: password
}
    }, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
    .then(function(results) {
        console.log('1');
        console.log(results);
        console.log('2');
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
        console.log('Error', response.status, response.data.errors);

    });
```

I tried to do `console.log(results.id);` and `console.log(results.data.id)` but i am getting only `undefined` as the result.

How can i get it.

Comment: `results.data.id` should be `results.data.user.id`

Comment: You have no `id` property on your data.  You have `response.data.user.id`, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @wZVanG I should have gone another small step :) Got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is:

```
{
    data: {
        user: {
            id: 65
        }
    }
}
```

You can acces to user data with `results.data.user`, eg: `results.data.user.id`

Answer (score 1):

you id is in user object, 
so what you need is :-

```
 results.data.user.id
```